# Adversarial Discriminative Domain Adaptation (ADDA)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to implement ADDA in Keras. Here is my code :

```
class ADDA_Images(object):

def __init__(self,modelInput):
    self.img_rows = 28
    self.img_cols = 28
    self.channels = 3
    self.img_shape = (self.img_rows, self.img_cols, self.channels)

    optimizer = opt.Adam(0.001)

    self.source_generator = self.build_generator(modelInput)
    self.target_generator = self.build_generator(modelInput)

    outputFeatureExtraction = layers.Input(shape = self.target_generator.output_shape[1:])
    self.source_classificator = self.build_classifier(outputFeatureExtraction)


    self.discriminator_model = self.build_discriminator(outputFeatureExtraction)
    self.discriminator_model.compile(optimizer, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
    self.discriminator_model.name='disk'

    input = layers.Input(shape=self.img_shape)
    fe_rep = self.source_generator(input)
    cl = self.source_classificator(fe_rep)
    self.source_model = Model(input,cl)
    self.source_model.compile(optimizer, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])

    input = layers.Input(shape=self.img_shape)
    fe_rep = self.target_generator(input)
    cl = self.source_classificator(fe_rep)
    self.target_model = Model(input, cl)
    self.target_model.compile(optimizer, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])

    self.combined_model = Sequential()
    self.combined_model.add(self.target_generator)
    self.combined_model.add(self.discriminator_model)
    self.combined_model.get_layer('disk').trainable = False
    self.combined_model.compile(optimizer, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])

    print('Source model')
    self.source_model.summary()

    print('Target model')
    self.target_model.summary()

    print('Discriminator')
    self.discriminator_model.summary()

    print('Combined model')
    self.combined_model.summary()

def build_generator(self,modelInput):

    gen = layers.Conv2D(filters=20, kernel_size=5, padding='valid')(modelInput)
    gen = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2, strides=2)(gen)
    gen = layers.Conv2D(filters=50, kernel_size=5, padding='valid')(gen)
    gen = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2, strides=2)(gen)
    gen = layers.Flatten()(gen)

    model = Model(modelInput,gen)
    print('Generator summary')
    model.summary()
    return model

def build_classifier(self,modelInput):

    cl = layers.Dense(3072, activation='relu')(modelInput)
    cl = layers.Dense(2048, activation='relu')(cl)
    cl = layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')(cl)

    model = Model(modelInput,cl)
    print('Classificatior summary')
    model.summary()
    return model

def build_discriminator(self,modelInput):

    disc = layers.Dense(500, activation='relu')(modelInput)
    disc = layers.Dense(500, activation='relu')(disc)
    disc = layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax')(disc)

    model = Model(modelInput,disc)
    print('Discriminator summary')
    model.summary()
    return model
```

But, it seems that target_generator is not connected to target model. I loaded target model from pretrained source model and then train discriminator and combined model in ADDA way. But, target model is not changed. It has same predictions (accs and losses) as source model all the time.

Here is summary of models :

```
Source model
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)         (None, 28, 28, 3)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
model_1 (Model)              (None, 800)               26570     
_________________________________________________________________
model_3 (Model)              (None, 10)                8774666   
=================================================================
Total params: 8,801,236
Trainable params: 8,801,236
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Target model
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_3 (InputLayer)         (None, 28, 28, 3)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
model_2 (Model)              (None, 800)               26570     
_________________________________________________________________
model_3 (Model)              (None, 10)                8774666   
=================================================================
Total params: 8,801,236
Trainable params: 8,801,236
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Discriminator
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 800)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 500)               400500    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 500)               250500    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 1002      
=================================================================
Total params: 1,304,004
Trainable params: 652,002
Non-trainable params: 652,002
_________________________________________________________________
Combined model
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
model_2 (Model)              (None, 800)               26570     
_________________________________________________________________
disk (Model)                 (None, 2)                 652002    
=================================================================
Total params: 678,572
Trainable params: 26,570
Non-trainable params: 652,002
```

I validated outputs from target_model's second layer (it should be target_generator by specification) and it is not same as output of target_generator (on same input). So, it seems that those two models are not connected as reported in summaries.

Can someone help me to figure out what is wrong?

I am using Keras 2, Tensorflow backend.

Answer (score 2):

Problem was in the training part - I loaded into the target model pretrained source model (load_model) and that made problems because it changed reference to generator model. Instead of load_model, I should use load_weights

So, loading pretrained model which works and not make problems with references is :

```
    source_model = load_model(modelName)
    target_model.set_weights(source_model.get_weights())
```